# startup.sh not found in docker

Tags: docker, ssh, vagrant

Hello I want to run this command:

```
vagrant ssh -c 'sudo /usr/local/docker/startup.sh'

sudo: /usr/local/docker/startup.sh: command not found
Connection to 127.0.0.1 closed.
```

First of all,

startup.sh exists on docker directory. Why it says command not found?

Comment: Can you post your Dockerfile? One issue is because you're not in the working directory that `startup.sh` resides.

Comment: Is this file inside the VM or some docker container? Please check that it is has the executable permission. `chmod +x /usr/local/docker/startup.sh`